# popup div remains open if clicked inside the popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that the popup div remains open if clicked inside the popup div as it contains a form to be filled by the user.. This is my code

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
$('#btnFieldWorkers').bind("click", ToggleDisplay);
function ToggleDisplay() {
    if ($("#div_fieldWorkers").data('shown')) {
       hide();
    }
    else
       display();
 }

    function display() {
        if ($("#div_fieldWorkers").children().length > 0) {
            $("#div_fieldWorkers").fadeIn(300, function () {
                $(document).bind("click", function () { hide(); });
                $("#div_fieldWorkers").data('shown', true)
            });
        }
    }

    function hide() {
        $("#div_fieldWorkers").fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(document).unbind("click");
            $("#div_fieldWorkers").data('shown', false);
        });

    }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="Add Field Worker" id="btnFieldWorkers" onclick="return ToggleDisplay();" class="btn btn-primary" />
<div id="div_fieldWorkers" style="display:none;" class="form_size"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search and help, i found out that this is working:

```
   $("html").click(function (e) {

        if (e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement == document.getElementById("div_fieldWorkers") || e.target == document.getElementById("btnFieldWorkers")) { }
        else
        {
            $("#div_fieldWorkers").slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
    function ToggleDisplay() {
        display();
    }

    function display() {

        $("#div_fieldWorkers").slideDown("fast");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the propagation when the user clicks inside your overlay:

```
$("#div_fieldWorkers").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Post a link with your code workink in the current status on jsfiddle. I copy pasted it from your question and it does not work. After that we might be able to help you. I always use the solution I gave in my answer and it always worked so the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nsZFR/7/
Check this out.. there's a little css problem.. i hope u understand..
I want div not to hide when user clicks inside the div. Div must hide only when clicked on the button named 'Add Field Worker' or anywhere outside the div.. Help me do this.

Comment: I know it's working in fiddle.. but don't know why it isn't working in my code..I am using the same code.
Does this make any difference if i have more div's outside the popup div?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but it's really hard to tell what the problem is without having access to the actual broken code

Comment: Is there any other way to allow div to remain visible when clicked inside it? e.stopPropagation is not working in my code.

Comment: It's the best solution possible. If it doesn't work in your code it means there is something bad somewhere else in the code. I suggest you find and fix that. Otherwise you'll end up stacking bad code over bad code and you'll end with a mess

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/XwcK6/7/)

Try this

```
     $('#btnFieldWorkers').bind("click", ToggleDisplay);

function ToggleDisplay(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($("#div_fieldWorkers").data('shown')) {
        hide();
    } else display();
}

function display() {
    if ($("#div_fieldWorkers").children().length > 0) {
        $("#div_fieldWorkers").fadeIn(300, function () {
            $("#div_fieldWorkers").data('shown', true)
        });
    }
}

function hide() {
    $("#div_fieldWorkers").fadeOut(300, function () {
        $("#div_fieldWorkers").data('shown', false);
    });

}
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(' :not(#div_fieldWorkers,#div_fieldWorkers *)')) {
        hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have update the code and demo try this, in the demo if you click on the text box inside  div" #div_fieldWorkers",the pop up will remain open

Comment: No this code is not working properly.. When i click outside the popup div.. it is not getting closed.. And when i click inside the popup div, it get's closed

Comment: @user2829939 can you describe your need

Comment: I want div not to hide when user clicks inside the div. Div must hide only when clicked on the button named 'Add Field Worker' or anywhere outside the div..
 jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/nsZFR/9           
Check this out.. This is my code.. it is working in fiddle but not working in my code. in my code, the popup div disappears when i click inside it.. i want div to remain when clicked inside it as it contains a form to be filled by the user. And when clicked on the button or anywhere outside the div, it should close

Comment: @user2829939, sorry for the delay ,I have updated the demo and code according to your need, without changing much of your code,hope this helps

Comment: Popup div is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

From code behind you can do it like follows

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "display();", true);
```